# Format for adding a second update to a query

Tags: php, mysql

For the query below, I would like to add the following action: update a column called "flag1" to be equal to a variable called `$uflag`.  What is the correct format for that?

```
UPDATE submission SET votes_up = $votes_up WHERE submissionid = $id
```

Answer (score 3):

Just like manual says

```
UPDATE 
  submission 
SET 
  votes_up = $votes_up, 
  flag1 = $uflag 
WHERE 
  submissionid = $id
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE submission 
SET votes_up = $votes_up, flag1 = $uflag
WHERE submissionid = $id
```